# I keep getting errors while passing strings as arguments to predefined constructor class in java

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using java and javafx (Scenebuilder) for this assignment, I am trying to pass some strings to its constructor I defined in its own class, but it keeps giving me errors even though I am following all the formats correctly. Please look at the pictures for reference. Working on this for hours now :')

Error: The constructor contact(String, String, String, String) is undefined

My contact constructor file called contact.java (line 9 & 12 for the controller def)

[image]

```
public class contact {
    private String FirstName; 
    private String LastName; 
    private String email; 
    private String phonenum; 
    //private String largeImage;
    
    public contact() {
        this("", "", "", "");
    }
    public contact(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber) {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phonenum = phoneNumber;}

    
    public String getFirstName() {return FirstName;}
    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {this.FirstName = FirstName;}
    public String getLastName() {return LastName;}
    public void setLastName(String LastName) {this.LastName = LastName;}
    public String getemail() {return email;}
    public void setemail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    public String getphonenum() {return phonenum;}
    public void setphonenum(String phonenum) {this.phonenum = phonenum;}
    //public String getLargeImage() {return largeImage;}
    //public void setLargeImage(String largeImage) {this.largeImage = largeImage;}
    @Override
    public String toString() {return getLastName();}
    }
```

Here's Where I am trying to initialize it contactviewController.java (Line 73)

[image]

```
    public void initialize() {
        contactcheck.add(new contact("elliot","Mathew","le@","1234"));
        contactListView.setItems(contactcheck);//bind contactlistview to contact check
        
        contactListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<contact>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends contact> arg0, contact oldValue, contact newValue) {
                selectedcontact = newValue;
                firstNameTextField.setText(newValue.getFirstName());
                lastNameTextField.setText(newValue.getLastName());
                emailTextField.setText(newValue.getemail());
                phoneNumberTextField.setText(newValue.getphonenum());
            }
        });
        }
 }
```

Here is where the observable list and contact check are being defined (Line 17)

[image]
Please help

Comment: I wanted to include my file names in there too just in case people might find that useful, that's why I put it as an image but sure I will add code blocks :}

Comment: help wud be greatly appreciated :')

Comment: Also add the exact error you are seeing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Java class name Should be stated in the uppercase letter. And also the constructor. So make sure your code is updated like this:

```
public class Contact {
private String FirstName; 
private String LastName; 
private String email; 
private String phonenum; 
//private String largeImage;

public Contact() {
    this("", "", "", "");
}
public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phonenum = phoneNumber;}


public String getFirstName() {return FirstName;}
public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {this.FirstName = FirstName;}
public String getLastName() {return LastName;}
public void setLastName(String LastName) {this.LastName = LastName;}
public String getemail() {return email;}
public void setemail(String email) {this.email = email;}
public String getphonenum() {return phonenum;}
public void setphonenum(String phonenum) {this.phonenum = phonenum;}
//public String getLargeImage() {return largeImage;}
//public void setLargeImage(String largeImage) {this.largeImage = largeImage;}
@Override
public String toString() {return getLastName();}
}
```

updated code for initialize

```
 public void initialize() {
    contactcheck.add(new Contact("elliot","Mathew","le@","1234"));
    contactListView.setItems(contactcheck);//bind contactlistview to contact check
    
    contactListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<contact>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends contact> arg0, contact oldValue, contact newValue) {
            selectedcontact = newValue;
            firstNameTextField.setText(newValue.getFirstName());
            lastNameTextField.setText(newValue.getLastName());
            emailTextField.setText(newValue.getemail());
            phoneNumberTextField.setText(newValue.getphonenum());
        }
    });
    }
```

}

Comment: the answer is kinda wrong, another user left a helpful comment